# Django Related Field based filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models based in which one is related to another.

```
class Contacts(BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='contacts')
    group = models.ForeignKey(ContactGroups, related_name = 'contact_list')
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length = 250, null = True, blank = True)
    title = models.CharField(_("Title"), max_length = 250, null = True, blank = True)
    twitter = models.CharField(_("Twitter"), max_length = 250, null = True, blank = True)
    facebook = models.CharField(_("Facebook"), max_length = 250, null = True, blank = True)
    google = models.CharField(_("Google +"), max_length=250, null = True, blank = True)
    notes = models.TextField(_("Notes"), null = True, blank = True)
    image = ImageField(_('mugshot'), upload_to = upload_to, blank = True, null = True)



class PhoneNumbers(BaseModel):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contacts, related_name='phone_numbers')
    phone = models.CharField(_("Phone"), max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
    type = models.CharField(_("Type"), max_length = 200, choices = TYPES, null = True, blank = True)
```

Here I wanted filter contacts who have atleast one phonenumber.

I have tried,

```
contacts = Contacts.objects.filter(user=request.user, phone_numbers__isnull=True)
```

Is it correct or not? Is there any other optimized method? How can we filter queryset based on related names?

Comment: Have you tried it by accessing data from from Phonenumber model . So you can get all Contacts have a phone number and then try to add all Contact objects to a dictionary to avoid duplicates with contact as dictionary key and phone number as value( value can be anything u need)

Comment: This method will output the correct answer, but it needs more query. It will take much more time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want,

```
contacts = Contacts.objects.filter(user=request.user, phone_numbers__isnull=False)
```

i.e check for `False` rather than `True`, as you want `Contacts` where at least one `PhoneNumber` is there. If its not there it will be `NULL`.